# Structure with array of function pointer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getSum();
void getDifference();

typedef void (*functionPtr)();

// assign the function's address
functionPtr arrayFp[2] = {getSum, getDifference};

struct true {
    int a;
    int b;
    functionPtr arrayFp[2]; //syntax may be wrong 
} w = { 5, 6, arrayFp[0] };

int main() {
    w.arrayFp[0];    //syntax is wrong 
    return 0;
}

void getSum() {
    printf("I am the greatest");
}

void getDifference() {
    printf("I am not the greatest");
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: I don't think you can call a struct `true`. Try running your code. See what happens. Research solutions on the Internet. If you can't find them, ask here for specific help.

Comment: @lodo Of course you can ... `true` is not a C keyword.

Answer (score 2):

When initializing the structure, you currently initialize the array with the first function pointer, not the actual array. In fact, as the structure contains an array you need to initialize the actual members of the array, either that or change it to a pointer.

Then when you want to call it, you use the function pointer as a normal function.

---

So for the structure, do either

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    functionPtr arrayFp[2];
} w = {
    5, 6, { getSum, getDifference }
};
```

*Or* do

```
struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    functionPtr *arrayFp;
} w = {
    5, 6, arrayFp
};
```

Note: Don't use the symbol `true` as a name, as it might be defined if you include [`<stdbool.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean).

Comment: the first solution is not working but the second one through pointer is working

Comment: For the first one ,I am getting errors " initializer element is not constant"